# Method openURL:options:completionHandler compatibility in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using the method openURL:options:completionHandler:, it turns out that in iOS 10 works fine, but I'm also interested in my app is compatible with the old iOS 9, but xcode gives me a

```
NSException:
-[UIApplication openURL:options:completionHandler:]:
```

Unrecognized selector send to instance
There any way make it work in iOS 9 also?
Thank for the possible response!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The new UIApplication method openURL:options:completionHandler:, which
>   is executed asynchronously and calls the specified completion handler
>   on the main queue (this method replaces openURL:)

This is under Additional Framework Changes > UIKit at: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html

you need use it like this:-

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: I'm using openUrl(url, options, completionHandler)

Shouldn't you switch open method with the openURL method?

Answer (score 6):

**New method in iOS 10:**

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL*)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options
  completionHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL success))completion
```

Read Doc here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html

> The new UIApplication method openURL:options:completionHandler:, which
>   is executed asynchronously and calls the specified completion handler
>   on the main queue (this method replaces openURL:).

**For below iOS 10:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];//URL is NSURL
```

You can use below code:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 10.0){

  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
    [application openURL:URL options:@{}
       completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
      NSLog(@"Open %@: %d",scheme,success);
    }];
  } else {
    BOOL success = [application openURL:URL];
    NSLog(@"Open %@: %d",scheme,success);
  }


}
else{

  bool can = [application canOpenURL:URL];

  if(can){

     [application openURL:URL];

  }

}
```

Also need to set `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in plist if not set:

Like,

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>urlscheme1</string>
 <string>urlscheme2</string>

</array>
```

Also read answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042291/5575752

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like as below for obj-c.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```